# Highlight visited links in Firefox 4

Tags: firefox

I have a bookmarklet that sets `text-decoration: line-through` on visited links so I can easliy spot what links I've already visited in sites that do not distinguish them with a different colour.

Firefox 4 has removed support for most visual clues for visited links and my bookmark is useless.

What are my alternatives to highlight visited links?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[NoSquint](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/nosquint/) offers several tweaks to make sites easier to look at, including custom link settings. It can also do this on a per site basis.

Comment: Looks like an option, I've try it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You might also consider Stylish. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/

Then to do what you want, right click the S, choose "write new style" ... then "blank style"... then paste the following:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

a:visited { text-decoration: line-through !important; }
```

And that should do it.

Comment: The add-on looks nice and I will try it but I'm not sure your sample style will this work. The problem is that Firefox only supports `color` for visited links, not `text-decoration` or even `background-color`.

Comment: maybe that's an old firefox. I actually added that style to see it worked before pasting it. It definitely works on 3.6.16 with the newest stylish. I think you'll find stylish is fun, it can actually modify the firefox UI itself, at least parts of it, as well as the sites.

Comment: It's a *feature* from Firefox 4: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/03/privacy-related-changes-coming-to-css-vistited/

Comment: oh, geez, I had no idea. So it's not working, even with !important? That's an awkward change... a browser that refuses to obey your css 'for your own safety'. They should make it an option, not just force it.